# How do I formally express that a statement is true only if 3 propositions are true?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

I have a rule: Action(A, B, C).

I want to say Action(A, B, C) is true only if:

1 - S is a member of set X.

2 - D is a member of set Y.

3 - T is a member of set Z.

I phrasing it at:

Action(A, B, C) only if 1, 2, and 3.

Is that correct and is there a more formal way to phrase this.

Comment: In symbolic notation you might say $((S \in X) \wedge (D \in Y) \wedge (T \in Z)) \implies \operatorname{Action}(A, B, C)$. Here "$\implies$" is the logical *implies* operator.

Comment: (Though I'm not saying that this notation is in general a good way to write mathematical reasoning.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"$A$ only if $B$" is equivalent to $A\implies B$ by way of contraposition since this statement can be rephrased more explicitly as "if $B$ is not true then $A$ is not true". A way to phrase your original proposition without symbols is then:

If Action($A,B,C$) is true then 1, 2, and 3 are all true.

Comment: Nice answer. I suggest adding the symbolic translation too.